# java unmarshal wrong conversion of à

Tags: java, jaxb, centos, escaping, unmarshalling

I try to unmarshal a String using this code:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAnyAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementWrapper;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

@XmlRootElement(name="Grid")
public class Marshal {

@XmlAttribute(name="Reload", required = false)
public int reload;

@XmlElementWrapper(name="Changes")
@XmlElement(name="I")
public List<XmlAttributeHolder> rowList = new ArrayList<XmlAttributeHolder>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Marshal.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        // à€
        String xmlString = "<Grid><IO/><Changes><I id=\"0\" Changed=\"1\" STT=\"à&amp;#8364;\"/></Changes></Grid>";
        InputStream inputStream = IOUtils.toInputStream(xmlString);
        InputSource is = new InputSource(inputStream);
        is.setEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
        Marshal obj = (Marshal) unmarshaller.unmarshal(is);
        System.out.println(xmlString);
        for (int i=0;i<obj.rowList.size();i++) {
            XmlAttributeHolder xah = obj.rowList.get(i);
            System.out.println(xah.getAttrMap());
            for (String formValue:xah.getAttrMap().values()) {
                System.out.println(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml(formValue));
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static class XmlAttributeHolder {
    @XmlAnyAttribute
    public Map<QName, String> attrMap = new HashMap<QName, String>();

    public void addAttribute(String name, String value) {
        attrMap.put(QName.valueOf(name), value);
    }

    public String getAttribute(String name) {
        return attrMap.get(QName.valueOf(name));
    }

    public Map<QName, String> getAttrMap() {
        return attrMap;
    }
}

}
```

I try to run this code in Java 1.6 windows and gives the correct answer:

```
0
1
à€
```

When I try to run this code in IBM java 1.6 CentOS gives the wrong answer:

```
0
1
Ã €
```

Why the unmarshalling instruction doesn't convert correctly the à (even èéìòù...)?

Comment: I suspect you need to specify the encoding when creating the InputStream. Also, ISO-8859-1 cannot represent the Euro symbol, so it's probably just dumb luck that that is coming through okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your input is actually a `String` I'd recommend passing that directly to the `Unmarshaller`, wrapped in a `StringReader` instead of trying to produce an `InputStream` from it. It's less error prone.

Try this (see code snippet below). Then you don't have to worry about whether your code specifies the correct encoding or does the character to byte conversion correctly for that encoding.

```
String xmlString = "<Grid><IO/><Changes><I id=\"0\" Changed=\"1\" STT=\"à&amp;#8364;\"/></Changes></Grid>";
InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlString));
Marshal obj = (Marshal) unmarshaller.unmarshal(is);
```

Comment: Thanks! I solved effectively removing the use of the InputStream and InputSource. In this manner the ISO conversion and other things goes realy well!